# Set cursor anywhere in window

Tags: normal-mode, insert-mode

How to setup Vim so you can f.e mouse click in the middle of new opened empty Vim window and place cursor exactly there ( f.e line 23 char 49), instead of line 1 char 1 because?

Is there better way than filling lines with spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To enable mouse support in Vim `:set mouse=a`
2. To allow cursor to be positioned (also by mouse clicks) anywhere inside **existing line** `:set virtualedit=all`
3. To add 22 new empty lines right below current cursor position <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>